# Is there a method to loop array.map() function?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native, loops

So, I have an array, which I'm showing on the screen using .map() function. How is it possible to make so, that when I'm reaching the last element, the next item after the last element will be the same as the first item? I'm thinking that it's possible to do by somehow looping map function, but I don't know how

Comment: Can you clarify?  It's confusing to see "the next item after the last element" -- do you mean you want to loop through the array multiple times?  It would be helpful if you could show an example of input array and the desired output.

Comment: Yeah, I actually wanna loop through array multiple times. 
render() {
 
  var SampleNameArray = [ "Pankaj", "Rita", "Mohan", "Amit", "Babulal", "Sakshi" ];
 
   return (
     <View style={styles.MainContainer}>
 
         { SampleNameArray.map((item, key)=>(
         <Text key={key} style={styles.TextStyle} onPress={ this.SampleFunction.bind(this, item) }> { item } </Text>)
         )}
 
     </View>
   );
 } - here is my code, I don't how how to show it correctly here

Comment: "multiple times" is not how I read your current question of "the next item after the last will be the same as the first one" because you then do not continue with the next item after that, etc, etc. When editing your question, there are helpful buttons at the top to help you format code.

Comment: If you trying to loop thru array multiple times what is your "finish" criteria then? You can certainly put your array.map() inside a while(){} loop if no such criteria is needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to repeat the first element again at the end of the list, the simplest way would be to add your first element to the list again.

You can easily do this with array destructuring and no loops need to be harmed for this.

```js
const myData = [1, 2, 3, 4]
const results = [...myData, myData[0]].map(x => `This is ${x}`);
console.dir(results);
```